# How can 'git bisect skip' be done in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, bisect

TortoiseGit has a GUI for running Git Bisect.

However during a bisect-session the context menu only provides 'Bisect good', 'Bisect bad' and 'Bisect reset'.

Is there a way to do 'Bisect skip' without the overhead of using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: See other answer that mentions that `Bisect skip` is now a feature in TortoiseGit.  Nicely done, TortoiseGit!

---

An excellent question.  In fact, I found your post because I wondered the same.

I haven't found a way to do it w/o the commandline.  But you can use it to do just the skip and then get back to using TortoiseGit like so:

1. Open "git bash" from the start menu
2. Navigate into your project
3. Issue the command:  git bisect skip 
   (thankfully, git bash shows you the relevant bit of the revision number you are on)

It will check out a new revision, and then you can get back to testing and using TortoiseGit for "bisect good" and "bisect bad".

The extra steps aren't that odious, but I await someone coming up w/ a better answer.  :o)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.3.1.0 there will be support for git bisect skip.

- You can skip HEAD from explorer context menu
- LogDialog will mark skipped revision
- LogDialog allows you to skip arbitrary revisions (even multiple at once)

See https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2505

Apart from using the skip feature, you can easily reset the HEAD commit to any other commit manually using the log dialog.